# Removing views in merge recyclerview adapters

Tags: android, merge, android-recyclerview

Since few days I've been searching for the solution, I have referred below merge recyclerview adapters.

https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter
https://gist.github.com/athornz/008edacd1d3b2f1e1836

They all provided methods to remove adapters but I did not find any solution. I tried make the root view gone, It's becoming invisible but space is still there.

I decorated recyclerview with simpledivider. You can see the light divider line in the image. Till then the view is invisible but occupied space. Any solution please?

[MergeRecyclerviewAdapter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk37K.png)

Comment: Thanks for reviewing, as I don't have much reputation.. StackOverFlow does not allowed me to keep it as a link .. So intentionally I removed s in https